# Why are falsy values and empty strings in an array rendered as [Object object] in Mustache?

Tags: mustache

I can't make mustache.js to load from github in jsfiddle.net, so I downloaded the file and tried on the local machine:

```
var output = Mustache.render(

    "{{#arr}} {{.}} \n{{/arr}}", 

    {
        arr : [1, 3.12, NaN, Infinity, -Infinity, 0, -0, null, "", " ", "0", 
               true, false, undefined, "hee"]
    }

);

console.log(output);
```

to my surprises, the falsy values are rendered as `[object Object]`, even though the [official docs says the `{{.}}` is for `string`](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).  The numbers 1 and 3.12 actually came out fine.  Note that they are the primitive type of number, not string.  The console.log shows:

```
 1 
 3.12 
 [object Object] 
 Infinity 
 -Infinity 
 [object Object] 
 [object Object] 
 [object Object] 
 [object Object] 

 0 
 true 
 [object Object] 
 [object Object] 
 hee
```

I wonder why the falsy values, include a valid string `""` are shown as `[object Object]`?

If I make it `arr : ["ha", "hee", "", "wah"]`, then all strings came out fine, but the 3rd one also came out as `[object Object]`.

If it works for `"ha"`, why doesn't it work for `""`?  If it works for `3.12`, why doesn't it work for `0`?  Maybe it can make sense if it is made to work for all primitive values?

(I also tried again using Handlebars, and all values showed up, except `null`, `undefined`, and `false`)

Comment: Works fine for me (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bgQ9d/), what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest Chrome in my case and yours... seems like your Mustache is different from the Mustache on the official site... and I am using that on my local machine...

Comment: So like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bgQ9d/1/) then? Maybe you've found a bug in the latest mustache.js.

Comment: This is typically a question that you should report here : https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues , not in stackOverflow... [edit] Wow just noticed post date : 31st of May, sorry :D